# detect if permissions revoked or not

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using a rooted M device and trying to access the permissions setting for other apps. 
I would like to know which permissions are granted or revoked by  user for each app
can this be available?

can   `checkSelfPermission()`  work for that?
Also, if I'm downloading an app which is not developed for M version can the detection operation work or not because I found that any app whit target version lower than 23 will always return `PERMISSION_GRANTED`

[checkSelfPermission returning PERMISSION_GRANTED for revoked permission with targetSdkVersion <= 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039188/checkselfpermission-returning-permission-granted-for-revoked-permission-with-tar)