# i've revoke the android permission, but checkselfpermission still return granted

Tags: android, permissions

my android project targetsdkvesion is 15, minsdkversion is 9,compilesdkversion is 23, i list android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in androidmanifest.xml.
i revoke the permission in Settings. then i debug my project, i find that the permission is already granted to the project, but in System Setting, the permission is revoked. (Tips: the device is nexus 5x , android 6.0)

my code:

`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_STATE);
    }else{
        deviceRequest.registerDevice();
    }
}else{
    deviceRequest.registerDevice();
}`

the code: checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED   return false.

i don't know why, anybody can help?

and i want to know if the targetsdkversion is less than 22, the operation revoking permission in setting can actually work? i guest the ui shows the revoking succ but the permission is still granted.

Answer (score 0):

You have target as 15, so when you revoke the permission still the permission will be there. If your target is 23 and you revoke the permission, obviously you need to get permission again from the user. If you are planning to integrate runtime permissions in your app, you must target 23. as simple as that.

Check this [checkSelfPermission returning PERMISSION_GRANTED for revoked permission with targetSdkVersion <= 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039188/checkselfpermission-returning-permission-granted-for-revoked-permission-with-tar)

Comment: my issue is different from his. although the permission is revoked, and checkselfpermission return granted, i can still read the phone state without any exception.

Comment: u say i must set the targetsdkversion as 23, does it mean there's no need to checkselfpermission when targetsdkversion is less than 23.    
so the old code doesn't need to check and can run in marshmallow device?

Comment: if you are target is less than 23 you don't need to ask for runtime permission because in your code **if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){ }** control will not go inside this **if** statement. but your code compiles because you had compileSdkVersion as 23.