# Android Runtime Permissions Not Working

Tags: android, permissions, camera, android-camera, runtime-permissions

This is my code to ask runtime CAMERA permission in Android. I call `handleCameraPermission()` from my `onCreate()`.

When I run my app for the first time, the permission is automatically enabled. I went to settings and disabled the permission. But still the `checkIfPermissionEnabled()` returns true but the camera doesn't start. So, what is the problem with `checkIfPermissionEnabled()`?

When I set `hasCameraPermission = false` and executed the code, there was no dialog box but the camera permission got enabled and everything was fine.

```
private boolean checkIfPermssionEnabled() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if(result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
                hasCameraPermission = true;
            } else {
                //not granted
                hasCameraPermission = false;
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void handleCameraPermission() {
    int myVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(myVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        hasCameraPermission = checkIfPermssionEnabled();
        if(!hasCameraPermission) {
            Log.d("cam","cam no permission");
            //if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                Log.d("cam","cam dialog permission showed");
            }
            //else {
            //  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            //}
        } else
            Log.d("cam","cam has permission");
    } else
        hasCameraPermission = true;
}
```

What I am trying to acheive is if the camera permission is not enabled, the default dialog box for asking permission should appear and I should get callbacks for the user's input i.e., get notified is user pressed Deny or Allow.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: compileSdk is 23, minSdk is 16 and targetSdk is 17

Comment: the targetSdkVersion is causing the issue. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039188/checkselfpermission-returning-permission-granted-for-revoked-permission-with-tar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checkSelfPermission returning PERMISSION\_GRANTED for revoked permission with targetSdkVersion <= 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039188/checkselfpermission-returning-permission-granted-for-revoked-permission-with-tar)

Comment: Will check that. Any idea why the dialog box didn't appear during requestPermission() call?

Comment: You're setting your targetSdkVersion lower than 23, so it's as if you were saying that you don't want to handle runtime permissions yet. That's probably why no dialogs show up.

Comment: When I changed the targetSdk to 23, the checkIfPermissionEnabled returned false but the dialog still did not appear as shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to ask the permissions in this way:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: It's there. Please check the if(!hasCameraPermission) block.

Comment: Delete boolean hasCameraPermission and try always use checkIfPermssionEnabled() method.